# C# SpreadsheetGear AutoFit failed to run on linux with error "System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform."

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I am trying to move my project from Windows to Linux. Everything works fine, but I get an error:

> C# SpreadsheetGear AutoFit failed to run on linux with error
> "System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform."

when I try to execute `worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit()` using C# on Linux. I have tried both SpreadsheetGear2017 and SpreadsheetGear2023 with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *SpreadsheetGear for .NET Framework* product (any version) is not supported on Linux, so it's not surprising to hear you are running into issues such as this.  If you need to use SpreadsheetGear on a Linux machine, you will need to use the *SpreadsheetGear Engine for .NET* product, which is distributed as the "SpreadsheetGear" NuGet package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetGear

This product targets .NET 6 and .NET Standard 2.0 and so will be able to run on Linux (or anywhere else where .NET 6 or .NET Standard 2.0 are supported).